# OBIEE: how to set 'is prompted' values in saved filter

Tags: web-services, obiee

My task is to automate testing of OBIEE report data. The main step is to get report's logical SQL.

I have dashboard with reports. Every report has named filter (not inline one) attached. So, I'd like to find a way to set up filter values and programmatically run generation of report SQL (so that WHERE clause is filled in with my values), play it and retrieve data. I have tried the following approaches:

1. OBIEE WebServices. First, I use *generateReportSQL*, then call for *executeSQLQuery*. This approach works fine for inline filters, I managed to set them up in . But I can not get it working with saved filters. How to generate report with values set up for columns in attached saved filter? No information in documentation or in internet found.
2. Generate Dashboard URL with all prompts set, run it and then read usage tracking tables to retrieve SQL queries. But it seems a bit strange approach, I believe there must be a simpler way to do the task. Moreover, usage tracking does not put information about report execution in its DB immediately, it has some timeout. Is there a way to avoid it?
3. *runcat.sh* + *nqcmd* - still, have not found a way to set values for saved filter.

So, my question is: how generate report's logical SQL with prompt values set for saved filter attached?

Thanks in advance,
Jol

**UPDATE**

Some examples:

1. XML of my usage tracking analysis contains the following:

   ```
     <saw:filter>
    <sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:logical" op="and">
       <sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:special" op="prompted">
          <sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:sqlExpression">"S_NQ_ACCT"."START_DT"</sawx:expr>
       </sawx:expr>
       <sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:special" op="prompted">
          <sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:sqlExpression">"S_NQ_ACCT"."USER_NAME"</sawx:expr>
       </sawx:expr>
       <sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:special" op="prompted">
          <sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:sqlExpression">"S_NQ_ACCT"."SAW_DASHBOARD_PG"</sawx:expr>
       </sawx:expr>
    </sawx:expr>
   ```

I can use *filterExpressions* tag of *generateReportSQL* to create logicalSQL that includes my values in WHERE clause. Everything is OK if tag *filter* is included in analysis's XML (the case of inline filters, as in the example above):

```
      <v7:generateReportSQL>
         <v7:reportRef>
            <v7:reportPath>report path</v7:reportPath>
         </v7:reportRef>
         <v7:reportParams>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <v7:filterExpressions>            
<![CDATA[<sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:string" op="equal" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:saw="com.siebel.analytics.web/report/v1.1" xmlns:sawx="com.siebel.analytics.web/expression/v1.1" subjectArea="Usage Tracking">
<sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:sqlExpression">"S_NQ_ACCT"."USER_NAME"</sawx:expr>
<sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:string">testuser</sawx:expr></sawx:expr>
]]>
</v7:filterExpressions>
.............................
         </v7:reportParams>
         <v7:sessionID>...</v7:sessionID>
      </v7:generateReportSQL>
```

2. XML of my test analysis contains the following:

   ```
     <saw:filter>
    <sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:savedFilter" path="/shared/myproject/_filters/myroject/my saved filter" name="my saved filter" /></saw:filter>
   ```

'my saved filter' has 'is prompted' columns that I'd like to set to my values and run an analysis to get dataset. But how to do it?

if webservices are useless here, what could be used?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since those are normally used for completely dynamic population in terms of content (instantiated variables pulled from user profiles, stuff gotten from prompts, etc....) you won't get them in the LSQL.

tl;dr - Robin wrote a bice post about load testing with LSQL https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2014/03/built-in-obiee-load-testing-with-nqcmd/

Edit: Baseline Validation Tool (BVT) was proposed and is the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

Actually, I am not doing load testing. I'd like to test the dataset that analysis generates. I have etalon dataset for certain set of prompts and would like to compare it with data generated by analysis (or compare datasets before and after RPD or Catalog changes).
 
I have read this article and this is generally what I am trying to do except that I need to have filter columns set to some values (not just 'base' logical SQL of an analysis):
https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2014/01/automated-regression-testing-for-obiee/

Regards,
Jol

Comment: Thanks for the update. My point is: You can't use the normal saved filters. You will have to provide a value yourself by either using a second (cloned) saved filter that contains literal values or variable calls or replace the saved filter with literal filters in the analysis itself.

Alternatively you can put the analyses on dashboards with prompts which provide the necessary context and then use the Baseline Validation tool (BVT) to compare

Comment: Thank you a lot! Seems BVT is what I needed!